# Empty first value on two comboboxes updating one another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

fairly new to c# and xaml so have patience! I have two comboboxes, the values shown in each are dependent on one another. To do this I used DisplayMemberPath and SelectedMemberPath like so:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="-1" x:Name="SiteLocCombo" SelectedValuePath="GeneralArea" DisplayMemberPath="Station" ItemSource="{Binding}"/>
<Combobox SelectedIndex="-1" x:Name="SiteCodeCombo" SelectedValuePath="Station" DisplayMemberPath="GeneralArea" ItemSource="{Binding}"/>
```

To get the first value in the comboboxes I added the property `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=True`
but now the comboboxes do not update each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the second combo to track the first combo's selected value...

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="-1" 
                  x:Name="SiteLocCombo" 
                  SelectedValuePath="GeneralArea" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Station" 
                  ItemSource="{Binding}"/>
        <ComboBox SelectedIndex="-1" 
                  x:Name="SiteCodeCombo" 
                  SelectedValuePath="Station" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="GeneralArea" 
                  ItemSource="{Binding}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=SiteLocCombo, Path=SelectedValue}"
                  />
```

Or alternatively, you can bind to SelectedIndex, or SelectedItem, etc in the same way.  This works for the case where both are binding to the same ItemsSource, otherwise you'll need a converter or a property in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks! What worked in the end was your code for SelectedValue, but I also removed the `SelectedValuePath` from both, and set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"` this has the comboboxes updating each other, but does not display the first values on startup of the form.